# how to let IE8 works as IE8 standard by default?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie8-browser-mode

I have added some polyfill to support IE8 and onwards.
Unfortunately, everything works well when in developer mode(F12 in IE8) and select the browser mode: internet explorer 8 . But when I close the IE8 developer tool, and open the same page, the IE8 complains a lot error which does not happen in previous developer mode( such as JSON is not supported error). 
I am really messed with IE8. How to force everything works as in the developer mode?(I need some feature provided by IE8)
By the way, i have added the following in the head section

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Thanks~!

Comment: It's hard to figure out the exception without lot of details like the javascript and your polyfil. It appears you might be using latest version of IE and not really using IE 8.  Did you try to lock down the documentMode explicitly to IE=8 to check if you get the same error?

Comment: @Baski,  I am using the exact IE8 to browse my website.  From following url: https://support.myeasyprojects.net/kb/a210/how-to-turn-off-the-compatibility-view-mode-in-ie-8-ie-9.aspx, i have verified that: when uncheck the "Display all sites in Compatibility View", it works well, and my website displays as normal. My concern is: How to control that configuration via server side or html meta? I can not assure the IE8 user will have that configure on or off.  Thanks~

Comment: Is that meta tag in an iframe? If it's in the parent frame, then it should work.

Comment: No, that meta tag is in the html document itself, not in a iframe.